# error (Code 123) php

Tags: php, cron

-that`s my code:

```
   <?php 

   $directoryIN  = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\OccasionTransferLeasing\\In\\"; 
   $directoryWORK  = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\OccasionTransferLeasing\\Work\\";

   foreach (glob("$directoryIN*.csv") as $f) {  
   $filename = basename($f) . PHP_EOL;
   }
   rename($directoryIN . $filename, $directoryWORK . $filename);

   ?>
```

-and it`s giving me this error :

Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\OccasionTransferLeasing\In\tab-voiture.csv ,C:\xampp\htdocs\OccasionTransferLeasing\Work\tab-voiture.csv ): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123) in C:\xampp\htdocs\OccasionTransferLeasing\In\FunctionRunByDaemon.php on line 28

what can possibly be wrong ? thanks!

Comment: Did you check both the path if exists, plus why are you using `PHP_EOL`?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Why are you setting filenames within the loop, but rename files after the loop has finished?

Comment: @Arvind PHP_EOL was the problem, i found it written in php.com so i used it , thanks!